# Is there a term for the kind of riddles which are based solely on not making an incorrect assumption?

Tags: semantics

Example - A couple who has 15 daughters went to the movies. Each daughter has 8 sons. Each son has 4 kids. In total, how many people went to the movies?

Answer: two (the children didn't go to the movies).

There's lots of these types of riddles - the "St. Ives" song, "You're a bus driver" one, etc.

Is there a specific term for this type of riddle, and the semantic trick it's based on?

Comment: 'Two' involves an unjustified assumption.//: << Mr and Mrs Smith went to see a film. How many people went to see that film? >> //// 'Determining relevant and irrelevant information' is educational terminology when people taking tests have to disregard the noise in a test question.

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense, *every* riddle is based on the possibility of incorrect assumptions. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddle) defines a riddle as

> a statement or question or phrase having a double or veiled meaning, put forth as a puzzle to be solved

In this sense, your riddle about the couple going to the movies is no different than the universal [writing riddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing-riddle):

> the enclosure is white, the sheep are black

where the page is white, and the writing is black.

---

You could argue that there *is* a useful distinction between your example and others, in that the movie riddle (and [bus driver riddle](https://www.riddles.com/1350)) lead the answerer to think that there is an answer that can be derived empirically (e.g. by doing math, or keeping track of the bus stops). In this sense, you could perhaps use the term *pseudoempirical* riddle. Of course, this would be a neologism which would have to be explained. But maybe you can get it to catch on!